Disabled Firebase but app still failing with Firebase exception?
I'm trying to build a debug apk from source that includes Firebase.
I've added to the AndroidManifest.xml (both debug and main), under 
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="true" />

However, when the app starts, it abends with:

Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
E/AndroidRuntime(10655): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10655): Process: [redacted], PID: 10655
E/AndroidRuntime(10655): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider >com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: >Please set your Application ID. A valid Firebase App ID is required to communicate with > Firebase server APIs: It identifies your application with Firebase.Please refer to >https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy/init-options.

It's using both Firebase Analytics and Firebase Remote Config.
I've removed that from the source, but I'd rather be able to just turn it off.
I don't want to deal with Firebase, how can I just turn it off?

While it looks like you still have a Firebase library on the project, probably firebase_core, Kindly search for the Firebase initialization code and remove it.
The initialization code looks like this:
FirebaseApp.initialize();

